# Counting duplicate words between two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to see how many words are duplicate between two tables. Therefore, I'm doing the following :

```
$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tableA a
    WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 from tableB b
        WHERE a.words = b.words)'
); 
$qry->execute();
$number = $qry->fetchAll();
```

I was hoping `$number` would give me what I'm looking for, but it doesn't.

`var_dump($number)` always gives me the following :

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "0" 
        [0]=> string(1) "0" 
    } 
}
```

...regardless of wether there are 0, 1 or more duplicate words.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: The query works fine, as I tried in mysql. I tried your query with identical tables which `words` are `VARCHAR` in both tables. Could you provide information about that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking about :) If you're asking if `words` are `VARCHAR` in both tables, the answer is yes, they are.

Comment: (Is there any way to up my question ?)

Comment: provide the good folk a copy of your db schema

Comment: Give us a sample data. It seems there is no problem in query.

Comment: Sure, I'll do this tomorrow (even though I don't think the problem comes from here, in my tests, I tried both an empty table vs a temporary table with 5 rows, and two tables (one being temporary) with 5 identical rows). (Just wondering : couldn't it be possible that the problem is with fetchAll() ?)